# adobe premiere pro only allows capture in HDV

Tags: video, adobe

I need to digitize a whole bunch of DV tapes using a Sony DCR-TRV10 miniDV camcorder, a 4-to-6 firewire cable, a FW800-Thunderbolt converter, and a MacBook Pro from 2013. Adobe Premiere Pro version 14.0.1 is what I have installed. Unfortunately, it only allows me to chose HDV for project, and then it says HDV video is not compatible with my input. How do I get Premiere Pro 14.0.1 to allow me to capture DV and not HDV?

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on Adobe Premiere and am now successfully using Quicktime Player to perform the capture. It's important to note that you need to separately tell QuickTime to capture the Audio and Video streams.